# full transparent object in openGL

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-1.x

I need to create a completely transparent surface passing through the origin of the axes and always parallel to the screen.
I'm trying to use this code (in `c++`) but the result is something like 50% blend (not completely):

```
glPushMatrix();     

    glLoadIdentity();                       

    glBlendFunc(1, 1);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(-100, -100, -0.003814);
    glVertex3f(100, -100, -0.003814);
    glVertex3f(100, 100, -0.003814);
    glVertex3f(-100, 100, -0.003814);
    glEnd();

glPopMatrix();
```

**Additional informations:** I need this transparent surface to get a point on it with the function `gluUnProject(winX, winY, winZ, model, proj, view, &ox, &oy, &oz);`

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by: "I need this transparent surface to get a point on it with the function `gluUnProject(winX, winY, winZ, model, proj, view, &ox, &oy, &oz);`". I interpreted this as "I need this surface to cover the point", but other people have interpreted it differently.

Comment: I'm using this surface in a way to take a (x,y,z) point on this. With gluUnProject I recive the coordinate of the object covered by the cursor and, using this surface, I can get a point on it.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to fill the depth buffer you can disable color writes via [`glColorMask()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glColorMask.xml):

```
glColorMask( GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE );
drawQuad();
glColorMask( GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE );
doUnproject();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. it is perfect (and simple) for my purpose!

Answer (score 1):

> Additional informations: I need this transparent surface to get a point on it with the function gluUnProject(winX, winY, winZ, model, proj, view, &ox, &oy, &oz);

No you don't. OpenGL is not a scene graph and there's no obligation to use values with gluUnProject obtained from OpenGL. You can simply pass in whatever you want for `winZ`. Use 0 if you're interested in the near clipping plane and 1 for the far clipping plane. Also you can perfectly fine just calculate the on-screen position for every point. OpenGL is not magic, the transformations it does are well documented and easy to perform yourself.

Comment: If I use values 0 or 1 for the winZ, I will have a fine solution only if I will not turn the scene...or at least so it seemed to me

Comment: @user3102760: that is not the case. YOu have to use the correct matrices, though.

Comment: @user3102760: No, because all the rotation and so on is covered by the modelview matrix you pass to `gluUnProject` essentially what glUnProject does is exactly reversing the process OpenGL does when transforming a vertex onto the screen.

Answer (score 1):

The blend function you are using is known as additive blending:

Final Color = (Source<sub>Color</sub> * 1.0) + (Destination<sub>Color</sub> * 1.0).

This is anything ***but*** fully transparent, unless the framebuffer is already fully white at the location you are blending (Destination<sub>Color</sub> == (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)). And even then this behavior only works if you are using a fixed-point render target, because values are clamped to [0.0,1.0] after blending by default.

---

Instead, consider `glBlendFunc (GL_ZERO, GL_ONE)`:

Final Color = (Source<sub>Color</sub> * 0.0) + (Destination<sub>Color</sub> * 1.0).

[...]

**Final Color = Original Color**

---

That said, you will probably get better performance if you simply use a color mask to disable color writes as genpfault suggested. Using a blending function to discard the color of your surface is needlessly complicated.